# NewView showing in PopOver instead of newView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

I have the right view selected from my PopOver but instead of showing in Parent View it is showing in PopOverView.

Here are some screenshots:
[image: PopOver]

After I select the Feedback option instead showing the view in my parentview which in my case is SecondViewController (grey background screen) it is showing in the PopOver itself.

[image: Selected View from PopOver]

For information I have Three VC's namely FirstViewController, SecondViewController and ThirdViewController each assigned to each TabBar item. I want to make SecondViewController as parent for the PopOver.

Here is my code where I create PopOver in my AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]){
        NSInteger index = [[self tabBarController] selectedIndex];
        CGRect buttonFrame = [[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] subviews] objectAtIndex:index+1] frame];

        PopOverViewController *popoverContentController = [[PopOverViewController alloc]init];            

        UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:popoverContentController];

        popoverContentController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(250, 85);
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:navcon];


        NSLog(@"X:%f Y:%f",buttonFrame.origin.x,buttonFrame.origin.y);

        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:buttonFrame inView:self.tabBarController.tabBar permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

    }
}
```

And the code in my PopOverController.m where I am making a choice of which new view to show

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    sendFeedback *sendEmailViewController = [[sendFeedback alloc]initWithNibName:@"sendFeedback" bundle:nil];

    downLoad *downloadFilelViewController = [[downLoad alloc]initWithNibName:@"downLoad" bundle:nil];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sendEmailViewController animated:YES];
   else
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:downloadFilelViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Can anyone let me know how I can make the reference to my parent view (SecondViewcontroller) so that the new view shows in my parent view rather than the popover view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert into popover UINavigationController and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` push newly created controller to existed stack (into popover UINavigationController), but not into tab bar.

In order to push newly created controller to second tab you need to assign second tab (now it is SecondViewController) to new UINavigationController and use exactly this navigation stack.

Code will look like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[navController pushViewController:downloadFilelViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I followed your code and I am receiving this error "Unknown receiver" tabBarController. So do I need to again create a tabBarController in the PopOverController.h file or otherwise I have imported the AppDelegate.h file to PopOverController.m file, but still the same error. Can you elaborate bit more on this

Comment: I did the same by using the existed tabBarController, but getting the same error as posted above. By the way I am adding the code which you have suggested in my PopOverViewController.m file under didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. That should work right. But the same error. Please get me out of this.